# C++ debugging using DOSBox

Tags: c++, debugging, error-handling, turbo-c++, dosbox

i was tring to debug the following code in DOSBox. when I tried to inspect the variable "int a" present in the while loop, a message pops up indicating " undefined symbol " but no such message is shown outside the while loop what can be the reason ????

```
void main(){

    clrscr();
    int a=10;
    int abc=11;

    for(int j=0;j<1;j++){

        cout<<"loop_1: "<<j;
        cout<<" test "<<a<<" ; "<<abc<<endl;

        for(int p=0;p<2;p++){

            cout<<"loop_2: "<<p;
            cout<<" test "<<a<<" ; "<<abc<<endl;

            int c=3;

            while(c!=0){
                cout<<"loop_3: "<<c;
                cout<<" test "<<a<<" ; "<<abc<<endl;
                c--;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Turbo C++` -- I seriously suggest using a compiler that was created in this generation.

Comment: Does turbo c++ have debug / release builds? I can't remember the early to mid 1990s that well..

Comment: @drescherjm TurboC++ shipped with TD. It was a fabulous debugger.

Comment: @drescherjm Never mind. On re-read I think you knew that. Has the variable been compiled out of TD's ability to display? This I do not know. Can't remember either.

Comment: ***Has the variable been compiled out of TD's ability to display?*** Yes, That is what I meant..